# Cost Of Passing Model To Nested PartialView In Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have some nested `PatialView` in Asp.net MVC.

**pv1.cshtml**

```cshtml
@model MyNameSpace.ClassDto
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.Partial("pv2",Model)
@Html.Partial("pv3",Model.FormName)
```

**pv2.cshtml**

```cshtml
@model MyNameSpace.ClassDto
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<p>@Model.FormName</p>
```

**pv3.cshtml**

```cshtml
@model string
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<p>@Model</p>
```

Now the question is what kind of these ways are better, and Less costly?

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are trying to deal with? What kind of cost? Maintenance cost, build cost, compilation cost?

Comment: I mean run cost,Project is web based,so it's important for client to feel speed in webpages.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between using `@Html.Partial("pv2",Model)` and `@Html.Partial("pv3",Model.FormName)` is neglectible.

When asp.net mvc is serving a page for you, the page should already be compiled (depending on settings, asp.net mvc version and so on, you can pre-compile all views on startup or each view is compiled during first call).

Compiling the page **pv1.cshtml** will bring out the following code (simplified):

```
public override void Execute() {
    Layout = null;
    BeginContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 79, 2, true);
    WriteLiteral("\r\n");
    EndContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 79, 2, true);

    BeginContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 82, 26, false);
    Write(Html.Partial("pv2", Model));
    EndContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 82, 26, false);

    BeginContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 108, 2, true);
    WriteLiteral("\r\n");
    EndContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 108, 2, true);

    BeginContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 111, 35, false);
    Write(Html.Partial("pv3", Model.FormName));
    EndContext("~/Views/Test/pv1.cshtml", 111, 35, false);
}
```

You can see that both calls to @Html.Partial generate same code for WebPage execution, which will call compiled views `pv2` and `pv3` code to generate html, execution time of which will depend on size of views.

Most of the time you don't want to think about how fast page compilation/execution is, because it's very very fast. Putting slow code to views will make view execution slow - do all 'slow' code in controller - never put DB access, api calls and similar things to your .cshtml, and your project should do well.